# My program doesn't run the main method, why is that?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods

For some reason, my main method doesn't run. I can't figure out why.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
   // public static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Scanner stringInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int UInput = input.nextInt();
    public static String[] usrNamePass = new String[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        out.println("Welcome to XYZ Bank! Please Login by typing  \n  Register by pressing 1");
        if(UInput == 1){
            registrationMsg();
        }
    }

    static void registrationMsg() throws IOException {
        out.println("Welcome to registration, please type your username followed by your password ");
        registration();
    }

    static void registration() throws IOException {
        out.println("Enter a username");
        usrNamePass[1] = input.next();
        out.println("Enter Password");
        usrNamePass[2] = input.next();
        out.println("Confirm your password");
        usrNamePass[3] = input.next();

        if (usrNamePass[2] == usrNamePass[3]){
            out.println("Are you sure you want your username to be " + usrNamePass[1]);
            Login();
        }
        else {
            out.println("Passwords do not match, please try again by pressing 1");
            if (UInput == 1){
                registration();
            }
        }

    }

 


}
```

I have no idea why it doesn't run the main method. This is the main file that was automatically created by my IDE; Intellij

I have done similar programs in the past and they all worked as they should've. I am confused as to why my main method doesn't even run.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What does happen when you run it?

Comment: Literally nothing. When I exit out, it says Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: Run your program and enter and integer e.g. `1` to start with. The statement `public static int UInput = input.nextInt();` expects an integer value from the user.

Comment: When I input an int it works, but I have no idea why Edit: Nevermind, thanks Arvind for the explanation!

Comment: I also forgot that Arrays start at 0, if anyone is reading this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine, you need to input an int after running the code in order to execute it further.

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: It's not saying anything in my run box. It says absolutely nothing. Maybe I'll try to run it on repl to see if it works there Edit: Same error on repl, copy pasted this exact code

Comment: Yeah sure, it worked for me though after inputting an integer.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked for me as well. Any idea why it does this? @Nikhil Singh

Comment: Because on this line `public static int UInput = input.nextInt();` you are asking it to wait until input is given from the user and then execute the code.

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that. Thanks! I feel like an idiot now. I have to wait 3 minutes before I can mark this as a solution.

Comment: Yep, I tried it again with it removed and it works fine. I just had to add it in other places. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just a suggestion, as welcome thing should come first before asking for input try to put that input line after the print statement, just for sake of better UX.

Answer (score 3):

`public static int UInput = input.nextInt();` is the static initializer, so it's called before `println` in your `main()` method, therefore your app awaits for the user input before it prints anything to the console.

You may want to replace your code with something like this:

```
public static int UInput = 0;

...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        out.println("Welcome to XYZ Bank! Please Login by typing  \n  Register by pressing 1");
        UInput = input.nextInt();
        if (UInput == 1) {
            registrationMsg();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that was my problem. It's fixed now! Thank you for clarfying!